# Having issue on setup Big Cartel domain with cloudflare

Tags: installation, dns, cloudflare, bigcartel

Having issue on setup Big Cartel domain with Cloudflare since there way to find the Cloudflare.

[image]

The option doesn't include the Cloudflare so all of us may think just enter the CNAME as we needed.

[image]

Can see that no matter how we test it won't approve the setting in Cloudflare even setting up with the redirect proxy.

Answer (score 0):

**After discover and doing research I think the redirect setup should be like this in this format in Cloudflare
See example:**

[image]

**Enter you domain with `www.example.com` in bigCartel and it would show the verification is passed.**

**Rule setup:**

[image]